# $location is undefined in angular js with require js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am bit new to angular js. Here I am trying to use angular js with require js. While configuring it I am getting a weird undefined error for $location while the error has not occurred for $scope.

main.js

```
  require.config({
        paths: {
            'angular' : 'core/angular.min',
            'uiRouter': 'core/angular-ui-router.min'
        },
        shim: {
            uiRouter:{
                deps: ['angular'],
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            angular: {
                exports : 'angular'
            }
        }
    });

    require(['app']);
```

app.js

```
(function (define){
    "use strict";

    define(
        [
            'angular',
            'uiRouter',
            'controllers/headerCtrl'
        ],
        function (angular,uiRouter,headerCtrl) {
            var app = angular.module('test', ["ui.router"]);
            app.controller('headerCtrl',headerCtrl);

            angular.bootstrap( document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], [ 'test' ]);
            return app;
        }
    );
}(define));
```

headerCtrl.js

```
(function( define ) {
    "use strict";

    define(
        [],
        function(){
            var headerCtrl= function($scope, $location) {
                console.log($location.path());
            };
            return ['$scope',headerCtrl];
        }
    );
}( define ));
```

Here when I am trying to get the path from $location its saying "$location" is undefined but $scope is accessible.

Please tell where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I believe you've missed injecting the `$location` service into the constructor array you return in `headerCtrl.js` (i.e. `return ['$scope', '$location', headerCtrl)`).

Comment: Yes I have found it. I missed that injecting part. Thanks miqid.